# How can i get object array in multiple input files function?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, angular6

My Project use Angular6 to create a multi-upload image file, and
I want to create an array object for sent to the database like this

```
  public foodmenu = [
  { "name": "hamburger", "img": "base64"},
  { "name": "pizza", "img": "base64" },
  ];
```

food-manage.component.html

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label">upload : </label>
  <input class="ml-3" input type="file" id="files" multiple 
  (change)="getFileDetails($event)">
</div>
<div *ngFor="let item of myFilesName">nameMenu : {{item}}</div>
<output id="list"></output>
```

food-manage.component.ts

```
  getFileDetails(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      var menuDetail = {};
      // Only process image files.
      if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
      }

      var reader = new FileReader();



      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
        return function (e) {
          menuDetail['img'] = e.target.result;
          menuDetail['name'] = theFile.name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "");
          console.log(menuDetail);
          var detail = document.createElement('container');
          detail.innerHTML = ['<div class="row"><div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12"><div class="card" style="width: 18rem;"><img class="card-img-top" src="', e.target.result,
            '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/><div class="card-body"> <h5 class="card-title">', theFile.name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, ""), '</h5></div></div></div></div>'].join('');
          document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(detail, null);
        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);

    }
  }
```

> Result

[image]

Comment: pass  menuDetail  in closure((similar with "theFile")  or use "let" instead of "var"

Comment: In general, don't use `var` but `let` or `const`

Comment: thanks Vladu Ionut and bambam,I changed var to let and finally,i got it!!